# Magic mouse connection issues on PC

Tags: mouse, bluetooth

Similar or same problem as the other folk with "magic mouse connection issues". magic mouse has to be reconnected every time I restart my computer. And it has to be done by "bluetooth settings". If I just change it from the quick menu on the top bar it falsely shows it is connected, but it is not.
I work on a PC, so it should not be a macintosh hardware related problem.
When I boot my pc as hackintosh I have no connection issues at all...? So it should be a software problem.
Any suggestions
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Not even kidding, I followed a youtube tutorial that involved a bit of aluminum foil and paper in my magic mouse and it FINALLY connected and paired to my computer... Apparently Apple messed up the dimensions of their magic mouse and those small changes corrected it. Here's the video I'm talking about: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=7vlDEVfV45s